# « (Du) (grand) n'importe quoi » : sens et nature ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, locutions, substantivation

> (Du) (grand) n'importe quoi.

[Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/nimporte_qui/54612/locution?q=n%20importe%20quoi#16001810) le présente comme un pronom indéfini avec un article indéfini et le définit comme signifiant « ce qui ne répond aucunement au but à atteindre » ; le DHLF (aussi moindrement au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quoi)) parle de la substantivation d'un locution pronominale indéfinie qui s'était figée pour « exprimer la désapprobation d'une proposition ou d'un acte déraisonnable » ; [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%E2%80%99importe_quoi#Locution_nominale) parle d'une locution nominale pour *fourre-tout* (« Cette catégorie, c’est du grand n’importe quoi… ») mais dispose d'une vedette pour [*grand n'importe quoi*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grand_n%E2%80%99importe_quoi) en locution nominale avec le sens de « chose complètement absurde, très extravagante ».

- Quel est au juste le sens et la nature grammaticale de « du grand n'importe quoi » (on a lu [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2699/3177), c'est insuffisant) ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre la question. Qu'est-ce que tu cherches à savoir exactement ?

Comment: Chose certaine, le sens a entièrement été étayé par l'exemple aujourd'hui.

Answer (score 3):

Il n'y a pas de réelle différence de sens entre "*c'est n'importe quoi / c'est du n'importe quoi*" et "*c'est du **grand** n'importe quoi*", mis à part l'amplification.

"*N'importe quoi*" est très versatile et selon moi les 4 sens en gras sont corrects (quoi que pas assez génériques). La locution elle-même est assez fourre-tout.

Concernant l'usage de "*du*", c'est une façon assez commune de qualifer quelque chose. Utiliser un [partitif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_partitif) (qui s'utilise normalement pour quelque chose de non-continu, non-énumérable) permet de donner un côté très général, de qualifier l'ensemble de la chose, sans avoir à préciser exactement de quoi on parle.

D'autres exemples avec la même construction :

> Vous avez fait *du bon travail*.
>
> C'est *du propre* !
>
> Tu peux y aller, c'est *du solide*.

Comment: Elle et moi, c'est `du` sérieux ;-)

Answer (score 0):

En termes de construction, on peut dire 'tu dis n'importe quoi', pas 'tu dis du grand n'importe quoi'. En revanche, dans 'ce que tu dis, c'est (du grand) n'importe quoi', les deux marchent. (Je ne saurais dire exactement pourquoi.)